# Printing a binary tree in Prolog based on a matrix

Tags: matrix, prolog, binary-tree

I wanted to print a binary tree by making a matrix based on coordinates which will corresponding nodes have in the tree. The binary tree is balanced and for every node goes that the nodes on the left are less than it and the nodes on the right are greater than it.

My tree is represented by a structure s(L,K,D), where L denotes the left branch N the node, and D the right branch. When it comes to an end the tree finishes with nil. For example, a simple tree with 1 as its first node and 2 and 3 its left and right node, will be represented as s(s(nil,2,nil),1,s(nil,3,nil)).

[Binary tree example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OqMld.png)

In this example, node 7 will have coordinates (3,2). 2 because that is its depth in the binary tree (counting from 0), and 3 because of its index in the monotonically increasing list of nodes of the tree.( the list is [1,2,3,7...]).

Basically I can pack a tree in a matrix of dimensions NxM (N being the number of nodes, and M being the absolute depth of the tree[in this case 3]).

For this example the desired matrix would be:

[Matrix example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HSvlL.png)

, where I put ' ' character - where the blanks are, in order for the printing to be achieved in the desired way.

Is there any way to code a function which will generate this matrix?

Comment: There are probably a few different ways of writing a *predicate* to do this. What have you tried? You need to decide how to represent your tree in Prolog.

Comment: My tree is represented by a structure s(L,K,D), where L denotes the left branch N the node, and D the right branch. When it comes to an end the tree finishes with nil. 
For example, a simple tree with 1 as its first node and 2 and 3 its left and right node,


 will be represented as s(s(nil,2,nil),1,s(nil,3,nil)).

Comment: You should put those details in your question. (there's an edit link). You should also show a simple example of a tree and its desired matrix.

Comment: I edited it. Thanks for helping me to clarify my problem.

Comment: One final note, here on SO, it's frowned upon to use image links to show information. You should try to add it as text. If an image is absolutely required, when you edit, there's an "add image" button that will show the image inline. So use that instead of the generic link.

Comment: If you look at your matrix, you'll see a pattern. Each column has only one element. Thus, for each node, the number of blank cells left of the cell for that node is equal to the number of subnodes in the left branch of that node, and similarly for the right side. You can probably use that information to build your matrix. For example, since the first row is the root node, then the first row starts with a number of empty cells equal to the number of left subnodes, followed by the root node, followed by a number of empty cells equal to the number of right subnodes. Process recursively.

Comment: I would also suggest that, if the only reason you want your matrix is to display the tree, then skip the matrix altogether and use the idea I mentioned in my last comment to just directly output the matrix view. In either case, you'll need to make an assumption about how wide a space you want for each node. Building a matrix and then printing it just adds extra work in this case.

Comment: Thanks for all the advice.